# How can I prevent ActiveJob from performing if the object it should perform on is deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have a background job that does some work on uploaded images, but sometimes the image is deleted by the user before the background job is performed, and it creates an `ActiveJob::DeserializationError`

Is there something I can do in the model in `before_destroy` to cancel the job? Or something in the job class I can do in `before_perform` to not execute the job if the record has been deleted in the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active job instances include `ActiveSupport::Rescuable` which means you can use [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) in a job in the same way you can in a controller.

You can then recover from any deserialization error:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob

  rescue_from(ActiveJob::DeserializationError) do |e|
    true 
  end

end
```

If you want to use this pattern in a lot of jobs you could extract it to a module:

```
module DeserializationErrorIsOkay

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from(ActiveJob::DeserializationError) do |e|
      # This error is okay and doesn't indicate a failed job
      true
    end
  end

end
```

which you can just include in your jobs:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  include DeserializationErrorIsOkay
end
```

NB: this recovers from any of the objects being serialized in the job failing to be deserialized

Answer (score 2):

This might be a more up-to-date answer:

`discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError`

See: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#retrying-or-discarding-failed-jobs

Example:

```
class RemoteServiceJob < ApplicationJob
  retry_on CustomAppException # defaults to 3s wait, 5 attempts

  discard_on ActiveJob::DeserializationError

  def perform(*args)
    # Might raise CustomAppException or ActiveJob::DeserializationError
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the record deleted or not in job class

```
begin
    record.reload
    # if no exception continue executing job
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    # If deleted exception is raised and skip executing the job
end
```